# Linear Algebra and a cube

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I am currently working no a linear algebra question and do not understand how to solve it. The questions gives:

```
Four corners of a cube are (0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,4,0) and (0,0,10).
```

I am asked to find:

```
Find the remaining 4 corners.
Find the coordinates of the center point of the cube.
```

Can someone help me on the right path to this question?

How would find the other 4 corners of the cube? I dont understand how to find the width of the cube.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure this is a cube?

Comment: Looks to me that the corners don't form a cube.  Instead, it forms a rectangular prism.

Comment: gain insight [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=list+%28%280%2C0%2C0%29%2C%282%2C0%2C0%29%2C%282%2C4%2C0%29%2C%280%2C4%2C0%29%2C%280%2C0%2C10%29%2C%282%2C0%2C10%29%2C%282%2C4%2C10%29%2C%280%2C4%2C10%29%29 ]

Comment: It is a cuboid as the answer below states. It says rectangle but the question was worded incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell this is not a cube because there are just three distinct distances between pairs of vertices of a given cube, and these are in the ratio $1:\sqrt 2:\sqrt 3$.

The four points you have show more than three distinct distances and the three distinct distances from the origin are clearly not in the right ratio.

Answer (score 2):

The corners do not form a cube but a cuboid. They are:

$(0,0,0),(2,0,0),(2,4,0),(0,4,0),(0,0,10),(2,0,10),(2,4,10),(0,4,10)$.

The centre of the cuboid is $(1,2,5)$. These can be seen if you draw a picture.

Comment: You are correct on the cuboid but how did you get that answer?

Comment: By just drawing it?

Comment: How did you find the center of the cubiod?

Comment: @user081608 To find corners, draw a picture.  To find center, note that the center $x$ is $\frac{2-0}{2}$, center $y$ is $\frac{4-0}{2}$, and center $z$ is $\frac{10-0}{2}$.

Comment: @anorton How would I find the center for all 6 faces?

Comment: First, draw a picture.  Then, notice that the center for the faces parallel to the $xy$ plane have coordinate $(1, 2, z)$, where $z$ is the $z$-coordinate of any point on that plane.  The rest of the faces are similar.